# jQuery Slider's user control not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So i've started learning jQuery, and I decided to make a simple slider.
Everything works fine, until i reach the part with the user control (prev/next img).

Can someone tell me where am I doing it wrong.

```
<div id="slider">

    <div id="slideshow">
        <img id="1" src="http://i.imgur.com/bWsaWvN.jpg" border="0" alt="First Slide">
        <img id="2" src="http://i.imgur.com/nhxEbVm.jpg" alt="Second Slide">
        <img id="3"src="http://i.imgur.com/OU3hY91.jpg" alt="Third Slide">
    </div>

    <img id="prev" onclick="prev()" src="http://i.imgur.com/v7KjugK.png" alt="">
    <img id="next" onclick="next()" src="http://i.imgur.com/xja1vLW.png" alt="">

</div>
```

**Here is the full slider:**

http://codepen.io/Chrez/pen/EVWdqe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace your `next()` and `prev()` functions with these:

```
$("#prev").click(function () {

    newSlide = sliderInt - 1;
    showSlide(newSlide);

});

$("#next").click(function () {

    newSlide = sliderInt + 1;
    showSlide(newSlide);

});
```

[Demo : Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1ybebm9y/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use addEventListener method instead of onclick attribute http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wKJQMo

```
var btnPrev = document.getElementById('prev');
var btnNext = document.getElementById('next');
btnPrev.addEventListener('click', function(){
    newSlide = sliderInt - 1;
    showSlide(newSlide);
});
btnNext.addEventListener('click', function(){
    newSlide = sliderInt + 1;
    showSlide(newSlide);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#slideshow > img#1").fadeIn(300);
    startSlider();


    $("#prev").click(function next() {
      newSlide = sliderInt - 1;
      showSlide(newSlide);
    });

    $("#next").click(function next() {
      newSlide = sliderInt + 1;
      showSlide(newSlide);
    });


  });
```